# How to add Ethiopic font to python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fonts

I have an excel(csv) file written in Power Ge'ez an Ethiopic font , but i see that when reading the file in python it does not recognize the font, just makes it question mark. I don't know how these fonts are used, but I know unicode characters can be used. But I don't know how to use/read them in python 3.6? I appreciate your help.

I am able to add the column names in pandas dataframe in Ethiopic font, but the result is NaN for all resulting dataframe output.

Comment: How do you read in the excel file? Where exactly do you see question marks? Without knowing more, you can't even be sure the problem is in Python, it could also be e.g. your terminal.

Comment: The question marks are both in the column names as well as all text in one column with "name" field which contains the ethiopic characters. I also edited the question. Apparently, pandas does output the field names but it gives NaN for all numeric and text data.

Comment: I read the excel (csv) file as `raw_data='hidar_2010.csv'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be useful.
But I can tell you how to use those characters in Python. 
This method should work for all the Unicode characters.

**Short answer**:
identify the Unicode code of the character you want to insert in your text.
You can have a look on [this site](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/ethiopic/) (I already found the Ethiopic subset for you).

For each character you will find two codes (the Unicode and the HTML), you obviously need the Unicode one (U + ...)
For example for the sillable 'ha' the code is U+1200. What you need to reference them in Python is this: '\u1200' (no '+' sign as you can see).

**Example.** It is important that you pay attention also to the encoding of your text file (you want it to be UTF-8). This is what I did for the same character:

```
x = '\u1200'

with open ('text.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(x)
```

Not sure if you always need to specify the encoding, I just decided to be on the safe side!

P.S. Worth mentioning: you can use this way of referring to unicode caracters also in a longer string like:

```
'The Ethiopic sillable Ha: \u1200'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So how do you include u\1200 to 137F characters?

Comment: @Kaleab If you mean all the characters between U+1200 and U+137F, I fear you need to use the specific code for each character. You can always build a sort of map in your script with assignments like ha = '\u1200' and use the name of the variable in your code, I did so for a project in which I need to use the IPA symbols. Unfortunately when it comes to less common characters (and even more so for non Latin characters) characters management quickly becomes quite labour intensive.